# Firebase 9 - cant login in authentication emulator

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, emulation

I can't login using authentication emulator. The emulators set up properly, the emulator UI works well, also the functions interact with storage and firestore.

**Firebase config:**

```
...
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();

// enable emulators
if (true) {
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "127.0.0.1", 8081);
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "https://127.0.0.1:9099");
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "127.0.0.1", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);
}
```

**Login**

```
...
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithCredential,
  signOut,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";

signInWithCredential(
  GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    '{"sub": "abc123", "email": "foo@example.com", "email_verified": true}'
  )
)
```

Error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'credential._getIdTokenResponse')

I am following the instructions of the firebase documents:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth

I added the env variable FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="http://127.0.0.1:9099"
The payload above '{"sub": "abc123", "email": "foo@example.com", "email_verified": true}' also coming from the documentation.

Also note, that without emulator - so connecting to my firebase project directly - everything works well, its just the emulator that I cannot make work.